# Why is my data not showing up in my TableView?

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

The data that I am retrieving from Firebase is not showing up in my table view, but it is showing up in my snapshot. What am I missing?

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase



class NewConversationViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    var users = [User]()
    
    let cellId = "cellId"
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        
        self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        
        navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        
        fetchUser()
        
        tableView.isHidden = false
        
        
    }
    
    func fetchUser() {
        
        Database.database().reference().child("users").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
            
            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                let user = User()
                user.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)
                self.users.append(user)
            }
            
            print(snapshot)
            
           DispatchQueue.main.async {
             self.tableView.reloadData()
           }
           
        }, withCancel: nil)
        
        
        
    }
    
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return users.count
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        
        let user = users[indexPath.section]
        cell.textLabel?.text = user.name
        
        

        return cell
    }
    
    
    
    

}
```

Comment: First of all in a `UITableViewController` both `dataSource` and `delegate` are connected implicitly. Connecting them in code is redundant. And if you are using prototype cells you **must not** register the cell

Comment: Okay, this table view controller is being coded programmatically, there is no view controller on the main. storyboard connected to it. Since I am not using the storyboard, would the prototype cells matter?

Comment: Have you confirmed that `self.tableView.reloadData()` is actually executing? What is the value of `users.count` in `numberOfRowsInSection`? Is `cellForRowAt` being called at all?

Comment: Those are great questions. I am new to Swift, so I do not know if the self.tableView.reloadData() is actually executing. I've tried doing this with mock array data, and that data showed up my tableView. Regarding your last question, I would need to see an example to know what that looks like.

Comment: @personalproblem ... you can put `print("some text")` statements in your code - for example, `print("count: \(users.count)"` above `return users.count`. You can also use breakpoints and step through your code, where you can then inspect the variables to find out why you're not getting any data.

Comment: it is working, but now, only 1 user shows up when I execute .childadded. When I execute .value, all the users show up in the snapshot but not in the tableView, any clue as to why that maybe happening?